# Heisenberg group over the Gaussian integers

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

If we take the entries of the (standard $3 \times 3$) *Heisenberg group* to live in the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, what is the structure of this group? Are all of its representations known?

Answer (score 5):

A quick google search produced [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2800). It gives generators and relations for the Heisenberg group over rings of integers of quadratic fields and discusses its representations.

Comment: Ah, that's a nice very recent paper, thanks. I'm for Baidu, though...